# Switching the FROM Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I currently use a code that generates an email fine with certain fields like To, CC, BCC, but I am not sure how to switch the "FROM" part of the email automatically.

Ie my email is here, but I want to automatically switch to another inbox, [image]

I can do it manually when the email is generated via the drop down, but I am wondering if there are ways to do this automatically.  I Tried adding `.From` to this existing code but does not work.

Here are the relevant snippets of code:

```
Dim OLook As Object, Mitem As Object, OlAttachment As Object
Dim fso As Object
Dim remail As Range
Dim acc As Object
Set Mitem = OLook.CreateItem(0)

With Mitem
            
                'send to:
                .To = send_list
            
                'send from:
                '.From = from_list
            
            
                'cc to:
                .CC = cc_list
                
                'bcc to:
                .BCC = bcc_list
```

`.From = from_list` is not a supported property.

Does anyone know how to alter this code to add the "From" parameter correctly?

**FULL CODE**

```
Sub Create_Email()

' Creates e-mail to send

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Emails Management").Select
    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    
    top_line_emails = 2 'hardcoded to row 2
    max_row_emails = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1  'last row
    ref_title_line = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Email Name", Columns(1), False)      'gets title row
    
     
    indexActive = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Active", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexType = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Type", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexEmailName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Email Name", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexsubject = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Subject", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexfiles = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Attachments", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexSendTo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Send To", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexSendFrom = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Send From", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexCC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("CCed", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexBCC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("BCCed", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexGreetings = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Greetings", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexBody = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Body Text", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    indexSignature = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Signature", Rows(ref_title_line), False)
    
    
    Dim OLook As Object, Mitem As Object, OlAttachment As Object
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim remail As Range
    Dim acc As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   
    user_name = Environ("Username")
    
    ref_row = top_line_emails 'hardcoded for row 2
    
    'finds the reports that were generated
    Do While ref_row <= max_row_emails
    
        Set OLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set Mitem = OLook.CreateItem(0)
        Set OlAttachment = Mitem.attachments
        
        send_list = ""
        from_list = ""
        cc_list = ""
        bcc_list = ""
        attach_name = ""
        whole_text = ""
        Body_text = ""
        
        If Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexEmailName) & ref_row).Value = "" Then   'looping down the rows, if it is blank stop generating emails.
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        go_for_it = True
        
           
        If go_for_it = True Then

        
            file_name = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexfiles) & ref_row).Value
            send_list = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexSendTo) & ref_row)
            from_list = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexSendFrom) & ref_row)
            cc_list = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexCC) & ref_row)
            bcc_list = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexBCC) & ref_row)
            Signature = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexSignature) & ref_row).Value
            attachment = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexfiles) & ref_row).Value 'not attaching
                                                                                            
            'On Error GoTo no_email, Gets the text of the Email
            Set remail = Sheets("Emails Management").Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexGreetings) & ref_row)
                                  
                                  
            'This section gets the text part of the email.
            If remail = "" Then
                greetings_text = ""
            Else
                greetings_text = RangetoHTML2(remail)
                greetings_text = get_date_cnv(greetings_text, ref_date_email)
            End If
            
            'Body text , Meant for charts
            If Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexBody) & ref_row).Value <> "" Then
                body_full_text = Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexBody) & ref_row).Value
                
                'count the number of < in the body text
                graphic_count = Len(body_full_text) - Len(Replace(body_full_text, "<", ""))
                
                For Count = 1 To graphic_count
                    'search the start and end of the graphic range
                    body_start_search = InStr(1, body_full_text, "<")
                    body_end_search = InStr(1, body_full_text, ">")
                    
                    'if there are <> then go for it
                    If body_start_search <> 0 And body_end_search <> 0 Then
                    
                        'isolate the text in the <>
                        graphic_area = RTrim(LTrim(Mid(Left(body_full_text, body_end_search), body_start_search)))
                        
                        'make sure the <> is not a <br> (line break)
                        If graphic_area <> "" And graphic_area <> "<br>" Then
                            
                            'body_text = body_text & Left(body_full_text, body_start_search - 1)
                            
                            graphic_area = Replace(Replace(graphic_area, "<", ""), ">", "")
                            
                            'pull out the graphic type
                            graphic_type_search = InStr(1, graphic_area, ",")
                            graphic_type = Left(graphic_area, graphic_type_search - 1)
                            graphic_area = RTrim(LTrim(Right(graphic_area, Len(graphic_area) - graphic_type_search)))
                            
                            'pull out the tab name
                            graphic_tab_search = InStr(1, graphic_area, ",")
                            graphic_tab = Left(graphic_area, graphic_tab_search - 1)
                            
                            'pull out the graphic area
                            graphic_rng = RTrim(LTrim(Right(graphic_area, Len(graphic_area) - graphic_tab_search)))
                            
                            Select Case LCase(graphic_type)
                                
                                Case "chart"
                                    Body_text = Body_text & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(Sheets(graphic_tab).Range(graphic_rng))
                                
                                Case "text"
                                    Body_text = Body_text & "<br>" & RangetoHTML2(Sheets(graphic_tab).Range(graphic_rng))
                                
                                'Need to put graph part here
                                
                            End Select
                            
                            If Len(body_full_text) = body_end_search Then
                                Exit For
                            End If
                            
                            body_full_text = Right(body_full_text, Len(body_full_text) - body_end_search - 1)
                        Else
                            If IsEmpty(Body_text) Then
                                Body_text = Left(body_full_text, body_start_search - 1)
                            Else
                                
                                If Len(body_full_text) = body_end_search Then
                                    Exit For
                                End If
                                
                                Body_text = Body_text & "<br>" & Left(body_full_text, body_start_search - 1)
                            End If
                            
                            If Len(body_full_text) = body_end_search Then
                                Exit For
                            End If
                            
                            body_full_text = Right(body_full_text, Len(body_full_text) - body_end_search - 1)
                        End If
     
                        Else
                            Body_text = Body_text & body_full_text & "<br>"
                    End If
                        
                Next Count
                
                Body_text = Body_text & "<br>" & body_full_text
            End If
            
            Set remail = Sheets("Emails Management").Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexBody) & ref_row)

            'signature
            Set remail = Sheets("Emails Management").Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexSignature) & ref_row)
            end_text = RangetoHTML2(remail)
            
            'creates the whole text in email
            whole_text = greetings_text & "<br>" & Body_text & "<br>" & "<br>" & end_text
            
            'create email, but does not send
          Set Mitem = OLook.CreateItem(0)
            With Mitem
      
                .SendUsingAccount = GetAccountOf("email@blah.com", OLook)
                .Display
            
                'send to:
                .To = send_list
            
            
                'cc to:
                .CC = cc_list
                
                'bcc to:
                .BCC = bcc_list
                
              
                'attaching files
                           
                On Error GoTo resume_here
                
                If Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexfiles) & ref_row).Value <> "" Then
                   file_name = Sheets("Emails Management").Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexfiles) & ref_row).Value
                                     
                   file_count = Len(file_name) - Len(Replace(file_name, ";", "")) + 1

                   For Count = 1 To file_count
                        file_search = InStr(1, file_name, ";")
                        
                        If file_search = 0 Then
                            attach_name = RTrim(LTrim(file_name))
                        Else
                            attach_name = RTrim(LTrim(Left(file_name, file_search - 1)))
                        End If
                        
                        ref_date = Sheets("Start").Range("D2").Value
                        
                        attach_name = get_date_cnv(attach_name, ref_date)
                        
                        file_name = Right(file_name, Len(file_name) - file_search)
                        file_name = get_date_cnv(file_name, ref_date_email)
                        
                        .attachments.Add attach_name
                   Next Count
                        
                End If
resume_here:
                
                
                'email subject
                .Subject = get_date_cnv(Range(ColumnNumberToLetter(indexsubject) & ref_row).Value, ref_date_email)
            
                'email body
                .HTMLBody = whole_text
                '.HTMLBody = graphic_desc
                
                'check names in outlook
                .Recipients.ResolveAll
                
                'display email
                '.Display
                
                'save as draft
                .Save
                
                '.Send
            
              Application.ScreenUpdating = True
              
     
                                                                
              Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            End With
             
                
            DoEvents
        End If
          
            
        ref_row = ref_row + 1
    Loop
    
    
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set OLook = Nothing
    Set Mitem = Nothing
    Set OlAttachment = Nothing
        
    Exit Sub
    
no_email:

    MsgBox ("Error creating emails: " & Err.Description)
    
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set OLook = Nothing
    Set Mitem = Nothing
    Set OlAttachment = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this function

```
Function GetAccountOf(sEmailAddress As String, ByRef OLook As Object) As Object
  Dim oAccount As Object
  Set GetAccountOf = Nothing
  For Each oAccount In OLook.Session.Accounts
    If oAccount = sEmailAddress Then
      Set GetAccountOf = oAccount
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next oAccount
End Function
```

You can then replace the `.From` line with:

```
  .SendUsingAccount = GetAccountOf("emailaddress@somewhere.com", OLook)
```

**Edit:** Follow-up to comments below:

If the above doesn't work then I suspect there's something with your outlook that is causing this. You need to think of ways/questions to help determine the problem, such as

- Is the account you want to use completely set-up within outlook?
- When you send email manually from this account does outlook ask you for password?

Try also to think of test code you can use to narrow down the possibilities that may be the cause of the problem. for example try to run these subroutines and see if the first code actually lists your desired account. Does the second code result in the account being `Nothing`? If so, perhaps an option is to delete the account and add it again to outlook, which may help reset something that was causing the problem.

```
Sub ShowAllAccounts()
  Dim OLook As Object
  Dim oAccount As Object
  Set OLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  For Each oAccount In OLook.Session.Accounts
    MsgBox oAccount.DisplayName
  Next oAccount
End Sub

Sub DoesAccountExist()
  Dim OLook As Object
  Set OLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  If GetAccountOf("emailaddress@somewhere.com", OLook) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Account doesn't exist"
  End If
End Sub
```

Try to make up some other code similar to this and please get back if you are still stuck.

**Edit 2:**

You need to make sure you set the `SendUsingAccount` property before you `.Display` your email: Outlook if funny like that :)

Try this:

```
Dim OLook As Object, Mitem As Object, OlAttachment As Object
Dim fso As Object
Dim remail As Range
Dim acc As Object
Set Mitem = OLook.CreateItem(0)

With Mitem
                .SendUsingAccount = GetAccountOf("emailaddress@somewhere.com", OLook)       
                .Display

                'send to:
                .To = send_list
            
                'send from:
                '.From = from_list
            
            
                'cc to:
                .CC = cc_list
                
                'bcc to:
                .BCC = bcc_list
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason this is not switching to the mailbox  I am stating in your code. The email remains as the default.

Comment: Ok, try changing the line `If oAccount = sEmailAddress Then` to `If oAccount.DisplayName = sEmailAddress Then` and make sure your email address doesn't have any typo

Comment: Thanks, for some reason not working, still going to default inbox. I have put the `.SendUsingAccount = GetAccountOf("emailaddress@somewhere.com", OLook)` where my `.from` code was.

Comment: I have updated my answer with ideas to determine the cause of the problem. Hope it helps

Comment: interesting, the account showing up in msg box is the default one, no others, aswell as the 2nd code says it doesnt exist!

Comment: There you go. I am not an outlook expert (nor excel for that matter), but I suspect the account is not set up properly within outlook. I suggest you delete it completely and add it again.

Comment: Hi, Ok I think you have to reorder your lines. A few things don't change/update after you display your email. Try assigning the account before the display line. I updated my code above. Hope this helps

Comment: Also, did you manage to get the test loop to display your account? Did you try deleting and adding the account again?

Comment: Thanks Super Symmtery. No the testing if the account is there still shows it does not exist, even after re adding it. If you give me a day I will upload my code in its entirety, it may be more helpful.

Comment: I have some time now, I like a puzzle :)

Comment: I uploaded it , but its very messy, give me some time and ill trim it and make it neat . Sorry about this master puzzler.

Comment: Hi, Sorry but I just cannot figure out what the problem is. The code is working fine on my machine.

Comment: @excelguy The question is how is this account set up in Outlook? I used the same approach as suggested here multiple times in my projects before with non Excange IMAP accounts. Might be that Excange accounts work differently (I have no experiences here).

Comment: Just to update, I am able to run the two macros `ShowAllAccounts` and  `DoesAccountExist` and the account does exist now after I went to file -> add account. It was setup originally using going to Account Settings and adding it through there. However the code is not working still.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry when Accounts are involved try to establish whether there is confusion about a second email address and a second account. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b

Answer (score 2):

Try the next approach, please:

```
Sub SendUsingDifferentAccount()
 Dim OLook As New Outlook.Application
 Dim acc As Outlook.account
 Dim Mitem As Outlook.MailItem
 
 Set Mitem = OLook.CreateItem(0)
 For Each acc In OLook.Session.accounts
    If acc.DisplayName = "testaccount@yourdomain.com" Then
        With Mitem
               
            .To = "..."
            .cc = "..."
            .BCC = "..."
         
            Set .SendUsingAccount = acc
         
            .send
        End With
        Exit For
    End If
 Next
End Sub
```

If needs a reference to 'Microsoft Outlook ... Object Library`. Or declare all above object variables` As Object`. But it is better to reference Outlook. You can benefit of the intellisense advantage...

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the loop and just hardcode it to my desired email? I got alot of code and I am not sure where to end the look and ifs.

Comment: @excelguy: Firstly, does the code change the user account? I did not test it, since I have only one account in my Outlook... Secondly, do you have so many accounts in your Outlook installation? And, if you are bothered by iteration itself, I am afraid only a workaround would be possible: To make the iteration outside the main `Sub`, in a function and receive only the account to be used (`As Outlook.account`)...

Comment: 1. No I believe it just opens the default inbox, im going to have to double check this, but 99% sure. 2. I have two accounts in my outlook, I can send from two different accounts.  Iteration is fine I guess, function would be easier for me.

Comment: @excelguy:  Theoretically, `Set acc = OLook.Session.accounts("testaccount@yourdomain.com")` should work. This is the way to change the user account. With or without iteration...

Comment: so would my code be : `Dim OLook As Object, Mitem As Object, OlAttachment As Object
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim remail As Range
    Dim acc As Object
    Set acc = OLook.Session.accounts("email")`  because im getting object varliabl eor with block variable not set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .SendUsingAccount property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach to send mails from a specific Outlook account (IMAP, no Exchange Server). The code relies on an already opened outlook instance (but that can easily be changed)

```
Option Explicit

Public Enum oCreateMail
    oSave = 1
    oDisplay = 2
    oSend = 4
End Enum

Public Sub RunSendMail()
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If OutlookApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Please open Outlook first.", vbExclamation, "Open Outlook"
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    'load a template for your mail if necessary
    Dim TemplateFile As String
    TemplateFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "template_message.msg"
    
    'Name of Outlook account that should be used
    Dim AccountName As String
    AccountName = "account_1@acme.com"
    
    Dim OutlookAccount As Outlook.Account
    Set OutlookAccount = GetAccountByName(OutlookApp, AccountName)
    If OutlookAccount Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Outlook account '" & AccountName & "' was not found!", vbCritical, "Outlook Account"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'send a mail from a specific account
    SendMail OutlookApp, OutlookAccount, "send_to@acme.com", oDisplay, "" 'use TemplateFile as template if you don't want to create the mail from scratch.
End Sub


Public Sub SendMail(ByVal OutlookApp As Outlook.Application, ByVal OutlookAccount As Outlook.Account, ByVal MailTo As String, Optional ByVal MailAction As oCreateMail = 2, Optional ByVal TemplateFile As String)
    Dim NewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    If TemplateFile <> vbNullString Then
        Set NewMail = OutlookApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(TemplateFile)
    Else
        Set NewMail = OutlookApp.Createitem(0)
    End If
    
    With NewMail
        .SendUsingAccount = OutlookAccount
    
        'remove a automatically added signature if necessary
        'RemoveAutoSignature NewMail
        
        'new email from scratch
        .HTMLBody = "test mail"

        'alternatively replace something in the template:
        '.HTMLBody = Replace$(.HTMLBody, "Placeholder", "Fill in TEXT")

        .To = MailTo
        
        Select Case MailAction
            Case oDisplay
                .Display
            
            Case oSend
                .Send
            
            Case oSave
                .Save
                .Close olSave
        End Select
    End With
End Sub


Public Sub RemoveAutoSignature(ByRef Mail As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oDocument As Word.Document
    Set oDocument = Mail.GetInspector.WordEditor
    
    Dim oBookmark As Word.Bookmark
    Set oBookmark = oDocument.Bookmarks.Item("_MailAutoSig")
    
    If Not oBookmark Is Nothing Then
        oBookmark.Select
        oDocument.Windows.Item(1).Selection.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetAccountByName(ByVal oApp As Outlook.Application, ByVal AccountName As String) As Outlook.Account
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account
    
    For Each oAccount In oApp.Session.Accounts
        If oAccount.DisplayName = AccountName Then
            Set GetAccountByName = oAccount
            Exit For
        End If
    Next oAccount
End Function
```

The following can be used to list all available Outlook mail accounts:

```
Public Sub GetAllOutlookAccounts(ByVal oApp As Outlook.Application)
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.Account

    For Each oAccount In oApp.Session.Accounts
        Debug.Print oAccount.DisplayName
    Next oAccount
End Sub

Public Sub ListAllOutlookAccounts()
    GetAllOutlookAccounts GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
End Sub
```

Comment: how come I cant run this? Do I have the right reference in my library? I run office 2013.  But I have micrsoft office 15.0 object library checked.

Comment: @excelguy Office 15.0 is 2013. But you have the wrong library, you need the one for **Outlook** not *Office*. So you need to check the *"Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library"* In your case `xx.x` is  `15.0`