# Designating the from email

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way of knowing why my email doesn't exist in my Outlook?

I am automating an email send but I cannot change my from email to my desired email.

I have two inboxes setup.

[image]

I run the below code and my account is not existing, although I can manually switch to it in the email display.

```
Sub DoesAccountExist()
    Dim OLook As Object
    Set OLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    If GetAccountOf("myemail@email.com", OLook) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Account doesn't exist"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You have two mailboxes in one account. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b

Comment: @niton can you explain? I have both added into my outlook

Comment: To confirm we have the same understanding. When you run `ShowAllAccounts` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731358/1571407 do you get "myemail@email.co"? If not you have to add it to use code that refers to accounts.

Comment: Yes after adding the account(using file -> add accounts) , now the two macros, `ShowAllAccounts` and `DoesAccountExist` work.