# How to send from a shared non-Exchange account?

Tags: vba, outlook

How can I change the `.sentonbehalfofname` property?

We changed shared mailbox from Exchange to normal account. Mailbox added to Outlook as a normal account.

With the following code I get:

> "This message could not be sent. You do not have the permission to send the message on behalf of the specified user."

```
'   Construct email
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "bbb@aaa.com"
        .BodyFormat = 2
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
        .To = currentEmailAddress
        .Subject = emailTitle & " ID:" & Range(teamMemberIDColumn & cell.Row).Value
        .Display
        .Send
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'Construct email
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMail
            .SendUsingAccount = Application.Session.Accounts("bbb@aaa.com")
            .BodyFormat = 2
            Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
            editor.Content.Paste
            .To = currentEmailAddress
            .Subject = emailTitle & " ID:" & Range(teamMemberIDColumn & cell.Row).Value
            .Display
            .Send
```

Please note the account of bbb@aaa.com must be added and configured in your outlook for this to work.

Comment: thank you for help .  i tried but mails sent by my account instead of that shared mailbox. even i wrote there but still keep sending from my mailbox

Comment: As the documentation says, the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) is to indicate the display name for the intended sender of the mail message (it does not change the mailbox). So it is to send a message from your mailbox but displaying another address as name. Also note that `SentOnBehalfOfName` only works with an Exchange Server. If not using Exchange this property does nothing.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you're absolutely right that's why I changed it to `SendUsingAccount` and demanded at the end of my answer that bbb@aaa.com be added and configured to the user's outlook

Comment: @SuperSymmetry Actually my comment intended to proof that `.SendUsingAccount` (as you suggested) is the right way to go if the mail has to be sent from another mailbox :)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ :) I was truely hoping I missed something and you would come back with a clue for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729844/switching-the-from-inbox

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you don't have permissions to send on behalf of another person. You must contact your Exchange administrator to grant such permissions.

Another possible way to send as another person is to use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which sets an `Account` object that represents the account under which the `MailItem` is to be sent. In that case, you need to configure the other account in the
Outlook profile. Here is the sample use case scenario:

```
OutMail.SendUsingAccount = Application.Session.Accounts(1)
```