# Sending letter from a specific mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to send a letter via Outlook (using Excel VBA).

I need it to be from the department mailbox.

Current code looks like this:

```vb
Dim Outlookwindow As Outlook.Application
Dim NewLetter As Outlook.MailItem

Set Outlookwindow = New Outlook.Application
Set NewLetter = Outlookwindow .CreateItem(olMailItem)
  
With NewLetter 
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "Stuff and more stuff"
    .To = "people"
    .CC = "more people"
    .Subject = "About stuff"
    .Send
End With
```

Is there a way to send from the department and not my personal mailbox? Maybe something like `.From` exists?

Comment: Maybe `.SentOnBehalfOfName` serves your purpose. If not, as far as i know, you could select the Account thats sending the email like this: `OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)`. Though this would mean that the other e-mail account had to be registered in your Outlook Application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching the FROM Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729844/switching-the-from-inbox)