# Can I send emails with macro from my secondary email address?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below is the macro I am using and it works. I would like to know how to modify it so it sends the email from my secondary email box. Thank You in advance for your help.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim olMail As Object
   Dim olRecip As Object
   Dim olCCRecip As Object
   Dim olAtmt As Object
   Dim iRow As Long
   Dim Recip As String
   Dim CCRecip As String
   Dim Subject As String
   Dim Body As String
      Dim Atmt As String

   iRow = 2

   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

   Dim Sht As Worksheet
   Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email List")

   Do Until IsEmpty(Sht.Cells(iRow, 1))

      Recip = Sht.Cells(iRow, 1).Value
      CCRecip = Sht.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
      Subject = Sht.Cells(iRow, 3).Value
      Body = Sht.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
      Atmt = Sht.Cells(iRow, 5).Value ' Attachment Path

      Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

      With olMail
         Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = Body
         Set olAtmt = .Attachments.Add(Atmt)
         olRecip.Resolve
         
         If CCRecip <> "" Then
         Set olCCRecip = .Recipients.Add(CCRecip)
            olCCRecip.Type = 2
            olCCRecip.Resolve
         End If
        .Display 'If you want to automatically send mail without any notification, use .Send. If you want see mail
              'before send, use .Display method.olRecip.Resolve
       
      End With

      iRow = iRow + 1

   Loop

   Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Although there is no mention of account the answers assume the secondary email address is as well an account. Would you confirm the situation so you get the appropriate answer. If you need it see `ShowAllAccounts()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729844/switching-the-from-inbox/62731358#62731358

Answer (score 1):

If you have your second mailbox configured in Outlook you can use the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sendusingaccount) property which returns or sets an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

```
    Dim oAccount As Outlook.account  
    With olMail
         Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = Body
         Set olAtmt = .Attachments.Add(Atmt)
         olRecip.Resolve
         
         If CCRecip <> "" Then
         Set olCCRecip = .Recipients.Add(CCRecip)
            olCCRecip.Type = 2
            olCCRecip.Resolve
         End If

         For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
           If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then
             Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
           End If
         Next 

        .Display 'If you want to automatically send mail without any notification, use .Send. If you want see mail
         'before send, use .Display method.olRecip.Resolve
      End With
```

Or a complete example which can be found on MSDN pages:

```
Sub SendUsingAccount() 
 Dim oAccount As Outlook.account 
 For Each oAccount In Application.Session.Accounts 
   If oAccount.AccountType = olPop3 Then 
     Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem 
     Set oMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
     oMail.Subject = "Sent using POP3 Account" 
     oMail.Recipients.Add ("someone@example.com") 
     oMail.Recipients.ResolveAll 
     Set oMail.SendUsingAccount = oAccount 
     oMail.Send 
   End If 
 Next 
End Sub
```

In case of Exchange accounts and sufficient privileges to send on behalf of another person you could use the [MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/bb206695(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) property which returns a string indicating the display name for the intended sender of the mail message.

Answer (score 0):

```
        iRow = 2
        
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Dim Sht As Worksheet Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Email List")
        
        Do Until IsEmpty(Sht.Cells(iRow, 1))
        
          Recip = Sht.Cells(iRow, 1).Value
          CCRecip = Sht.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
          Subject = Sht.Cells(iRow, 3).Value
          Body = Sht.Cells(iRow, 4).Value
          Atmt = Sht.Cells(iRow, 5).Value ' Attachment Path
        
          Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        'Get the other account by using the email or use index olMail.Session.Accounts.Item(1) 
        Set OutAccount = olMail.Session.Accounts.Item("other.email.address@something.com") 
        
          With olMail
             Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
            .Subject = Subject
            .Body = Body
             Set olAtmt = .Attachments.Add(Atmt)
             olRecip.Resolve
             
             If CCRecip <> "" Then
             Set olCCRecip = .Recipients.Add(CCRecip)
                olCCRecip.Type = 2
                olCCRecip.Resolve
             End If
           'set the account to be used to send the email
            Set .SendUsingAccount = OutAccount
            .Display 'If you want to automatically send mail without any notification, use .Send. If you want see mail
                  'before send, use .Display method.olRecip.Resolve
           
          End With
        
          iRow = iRow + 1
       Loop

       Set olApp = Nothing End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, It didn't work. Just showing sections I edited as it won't let me paste the whole code                                                       
   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim o1OutAccount As Object
   Dim iRow As Long
   Dim OutApp As String

   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set o1OutAccount = OutApp.Session.Accounts.Item("email")

         End If
          'set the account to be used to send the email
            Set .SendUsingAccount = o1OutAccount

Comment: there was a typo, i've updated it, please try again

Comment: thanks so much for your help, still no luck. on the top I am adding  Dim o1OutAccount As Object and Dim OutAccount As String, then I am adding what you have provided 'Get the other account by using the email or use index olApp.Session.Accounts.Item(1)
   Set OutAccount = olApp.Session.Accounts.Item("email") and towards the end 'set the account to be used to send the email
            Set .SendUsingAccount = o1OutAccount ; for the Set OutAccount = o1App ...section. it is showing an object error, when I add o1in front of OutAccount I get an invalid procedure call or argument error

Comment: sorry, I wish I could send this so it's a bit clearer

Comment: it was me again, apologies i used wrong instance of object, please give a try again, i've made the change to the code above

make sure to replace "other.email.address@something.com" with valid email of your secondary account or use olMail.Session.Accounts.Item(1) or olMail.Session.Accounts.Item(0)