# Switch accounts in outlook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a working VBA to send Outlook mail using Excel VBA as shown below:

```
Sub Send_email_fromexcel()
Dim edress As String
Dim subj As String
Dim message As String
Dim filename, fname2 As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim myAttachments As Object
Dim path As String
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim attachment As String
Dim x As Integer


 x = 2

Do While Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) <> ""
   
    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.CreateItem(0)
    Set myAttachments = outlookmailitem.Attachments
    path = "C:\FILES\"
    edress = Sheet1.Cells(x, 1)
   
      
    subj = Sheet1.Cells(x, 2)
    filename = Sheet1.Cells(x, 3)
    fname2 = "logo.png"
    attachment = path + filename

    
        outlookmailitem.To = edress
        outlookmailitem.cc = ""
        outlookmailitem.bcc = ""
        outlookmailitem.Subject = subj
        outlookmailitem.Attachments.Add path & fname2, 0
        outlookmailitem.HTMLBody = "Hi " & Sheet1.Cells(x, 4) & ",<br>" _
        & "<br>Body of email goes here.<br>" _
        & "<br><img src='logo.png'>"
            
        myAttachments.Add (attachment)
        outlookmailitem.display
        'outlookmailitem.send
            
            
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
        edress = ""
    x = x + 1

Loop


Set outlookapp = Nothing
Set outlookmailitem = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have 2 Outlook accounts and would like to send using the second. I found a tutorial online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EAAEJIOM9I&list=PL1R_HJw0CDYJO6Pa8m_ZsoERuL44fwkdR&index=6) to specify which account to use but not sure how to incorporate it to my code above. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching the FROM Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62729844/switching-the-from-inbox)